# Powerbuilder GET request with request headers

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm accessing a RESTFUL API using Powerbuilder. I have it working just fine however, I would like to call the API and  include request headers. The reason I need this is because the API accepts a "Content-Type" request header, which can be set to either "application/xml" or "application/json".

Here is what I have done so far:

```
inet iinet_base
n_ir ir

GetContextService( "Internet", iinet_base )
CREATE n_ir
li_rc = iinet_base.GetURL( "http://api.com/apicall", ir )
ls_result = ir.of_getResultData_String()
```

The above will return the data as expected. The request must be a GET request, not a POST.

**How do I add a Request Header to the GetURL request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up not using the inet object and instead using something else. Long story short, I'm now using an OleObject like this

```
lole_Send.connectToNewObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
lole_SrvHTTP.connectToNewObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
lole_SrvHTTP.Open("GET", "http://api.com/apicall", FALSE)
lole_SrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json")
lole_SrvHTTP.Send(lole_Send)
ls_message = string(lole_SrvHTTP.Status)
ls_response = string(lole_SrvHTTP.ResponseText)
```

There is more to it, however this is a good start for someone else trying to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use instead the `PostUrl()` method of the `inet` object that let you specify some request headers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the API only accepts GET requests, not POST requests. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add header you can use more SetRequestHeader

Sample curl

> *curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json --header 'Authorization: asdfasdf' --header 'APIKEY: ssss'*

like this

```
lole_Send.connectToNewObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
lole_SrvHTTP.connectToNewObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
lole_SrvHTTP.Open("GET", "http://api.com/apicall", FALSE)

lole_SrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json")
lole_SrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader( "Authorization", "asdfasdf' )*")
lole_SrvHTTP.SetRequestHeader( "APIKEY", "ssss")

lole_SrvHTTP.Send(lole_Send)
ls_message = string(lole_SrvHTTP.Status)
ls_response = string(lole_SrvHTTP.ResponseText)
```